# rounded corner image for small cube

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, css, lightbox

how to show the image in the small cube rounded corner....
the image in the light box is rounded corner....
actual image is here

http://www.defie.co/designerImages/inventoryControl.png

http://jsfiddle.net/ZrpLT/91/

providing my code below

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        Gallery.setOptions({
            size:     150,
            lightbox: true,
            //animation:  'drop'
            //speed:      500,
            //closeOnEsc: true,
            //slideshow:  false,
            //slideshow_speed: 3000,
            //cube_speed: 1000
        });
    </script>
    <style>
        body {
            background: #AAAAAA;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="span10">
                <div class="melonhtml5_gallery">
                                <div data-caption="&lt;a style='margin-left: 92px; font-size: 18px;' href='http://www.w3schools.com/' &gt;Create&lt;/a&gt; &lt;div&gt; &lt;a style='margin-left: 92px; font-size: 18px;' &gt;View/Edit&lt;/a&gt; &lt;/div&gt; &lt;a style='margin-left: 92px; font-size: 18px;' &gt;Labels&lt;/a&gt;" data-image="http://www.defie.co/designerImages/inventoryControl.png"></div>



            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you'd like the rotating cube to have rounded corners, similar to the image but in 3D.

You could *sort of* give it a rounded corner feel, but because there are layers in the background as the cube rotates, the effect fails.

```
div.melonhtml5_gallery div.cube div,
div.melonhtml5_gallery div.cube div img {
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

Here's a similar attempt at quasi-rounded corners in CSS3: http://3dcube.pixelass.com/

CSS3 transforms are limited to matrix transformations on 2-dimensional boxes, so creating 3D-looking objects is usually achieved by some clever trick or illusion. In this case, that illusion fails when the corners are rounded. To get a truly rounded rotating cube, I think you'll have to use something like WebGL.

Comment: but the front face is not rounded corner

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant by "the illusion fails when the corners are rounded." If you look at the individual faces (http://jsfiddle.net/ZrpLT/96/), they are all rounded, but because we can now "see through" to the back layers even when we are looking at the front face, we don't notice the rounded corners. There might be some clever effect where you somehow change the background layer colors/images/opacity at just the right time to hide them, but I doubt that library supports anything like this.